# How can I handle Enter Key Press in DataGridView when the Cell is in EditMode?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a `DataGridView` and I have made `AllowUserToAddRows` property to `false` and in `Load` event handler of form, I added a new row to the grid using a function. Now, when user edits the datagidview and once he ends edit and presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> I want to call that function to add a new row to grid again.

I tried `KeyDown` event of `DataGridView`, but it seems the event will not trigger when the cell is in edit mode.

Comment: What have you tried? This is very vague. I'm not too familiar with the datagridview but if it has a KeyDown event you can do a check to see if the key was enter. If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then 'my code

Comment: On the enter key press in the cell it should call a function. When the cell is in edit mode keydown event will not trigger so. Thanks

Comment: What will you do if the user is only wants to edit a cell and don't want to add a new row? I recommend you forget about pressing enter and just use a shortcut key for adding new record. Also I can't see any reason about disallowing user to add row manually when you will allow him to add record using a shortcut key (even like you want to do using enter).

Answer (score 1):

```
 Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message, ByVal keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean
If msg.WParam.ToInt32() = Keys.Enter Then
  DataGridView1.EndEdit()
  MessageBox.Show("Enter key is pressed")
  Return True
End If

Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

Use this function with your condition

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft says that you can't add a new row to a databound DataGridView but that is not true.
I assume that you want add a new row to the end of the grid. By default the DataGridView control has an empty row with the index -1 at the bottom of the grid. To add a new row programmatically do this:

```
Dim rowindex as Int32
rowIndex = 
DataGridView1.Rows.GetLastRow(includeFilter:=0)
DataGridView1.CurrentCell = 
DataGridView1.Rows.Item(rowIndex).Cells(1)
DataGridView1.BeginEdit(selectAll:=True)
```

This gives you a new row. If you set the DataGridView to EditOnEnter you will see the pen icon on the far left when you click on a cell.